# Python insert Dict into sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database where the first column is the `id` and set as primary key with auto increment. I'm trying to insert the values from my python dictionary as such:

```py
value = {'host': [], 'drive': [], 'percent': []}
soup = bs(contents, 'html.parser')
for name in soup.find_all("td", class_="qqp0_c0"):
    hostname = name.parent.find('td').get_text()
    drive = name.parent.find('td', class_="qqp0_c1").get_text()
    used_percent = name.parent.find('td', class_="qqp0_c5").get_text()
    value['host'].append(hostname)
    value['drive'].append(drive)
    value['percent'].append(used_percent)
    #cur.executemany("INSERT INTO scrap VALUES (?, ?, ?)", hostname, drive, used_percent)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap VALUES (?, ?, ?);", value)
```

I keep getting errors, my latest error seems to imply it needs an `id` value:

> cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap VALUES (?, ?, ?);", value)
> sqlite3.OperationalError: table scrap has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied

Do I need to supply an `id` number?

This is the db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE scrap (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    hostname VARCHAR(255),
    drive VARCHAR(255),
    perc VARCHAR(255)
       );
```

Comment: What is the `CREATE` statement used to create the table you are trying to `INSERT` into? What happens if you pass 4 values? You should be able to just pass 3 values if the column is correctly set up as autoincrement.

Comment: not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `id` column is auto-incrementing you don't need to supply a value for it, but you do need to "tell" the database that you aren't inserting it. Note that in order to bind a dictionary, you need to specify the placeholders by name:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap (hostname, drive, perc) VALUES (:host, :drive, :percent);", value)
```

**EDIT:**
Following up on the discussion from the comments - the `value` dictionary should map placeholder names to their intended values, not list containing them:

```py
soup = bs(contents, 'html.parser')
for name in soup.find_all("td", class_="qqp0_c0"):
    hostname = name.parent.find('td').get_text()
    drive = name.parent.find('td', class_="qqp0_c1").get_text()
    used_percent = name.parent.find('td', class_="qqp0_c5").get_text()
    value = {'host': hostname, 'drive': drive, 'percent': used_percent}  
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap (hostname, drive, perc) VALUES (:host, :drive, :percent);", value)
```

Comment: This is the error output from running it like that:                                                
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap (hostname, drive, perc) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", value)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Binding 1 has no name, but you supplied a dictionary (which has only names).

Comment: This is my db schema:                                                                                                 
    CREATE TABLE scrap (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        hostname VARCHAR(255),
        drive VARCHAR(255),
        perc VARCHAR(255)
);

Comment: @codereber I missed fixing the placeholder names. See my edited answer.

Comment: this is the error after fixing the placeholder names:                                
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap (hostname, drive, perc) VALUES (:hostname, :drive, :used_percent);", value)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.

Comment: @codereber sorry, the key in your dictionary is "percent", not "used_percent" - my bad. Edited and fixed, again.

Comment: no joy same error                                                                                    
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap (hostname, drive, perc) VALUES (:hostname, :drive, :percent);", value)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.

Comment: really seems like it wants something for the id value

Comment: @codereber I'm not on top of my game today - ":hostname" was supposed to be ":host". Edited again.

Comment: ok np, got a new error at least:                                                               
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrap (hostname, drive, perc) VALUES (:host, :drive, :percent);", value)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter :host - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @codereber Looks like its related to the lists you have in the dict. Can you use a new dict for every iteration of the loop with plain old strings in it?

Comment: not sure can you give me a example what you mean

Comment: @codereber it's a bit long to explain in the comments - see my edited again answer